# Add private method to class by mixin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, redmine, redmine-plugins

I want to add an `after_create` callback to **Role** model by my plugin. So I can add an `after_callback :my_private_method` by `class_eval` as usual. I can add public method by defining it in `InstanceMethods` in the module that mixined in **Role** model.


But how I can add a private method `my_private_method` to **Role** model for using in `after_create` callback?

I know that this can be implemented by `class_eval` but is there any nicer solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh it was really easy:

```
module RolePatch
  module InstanceMethods
    private    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<   It works like a charm.
    def my_private_method; end
  end

  def self.included(receiver)
    receiver.send :include, InstanceMethods

    receiver.class_eval do
      after_create :my_private_method
    end
  end
end

1.9.3p392 :017 > Role.first.private_methods.grep(/my_private_method/)
 => [:my_private_method]
```

So we can use private modifier in module `InstanceMethods` as usual.